# How to slide a popup (html) with parameters and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, popup

I have in my webpage this html popup:

```
<div class="popup1" id="popup_calendar">
<div class="bg_popup"></div>
<div class="content_popup">
    <a href="javascript:closePopup();" class="btn"></a>
    <div class="popup_content">
        <h2>Content Detail</h2>
        <div class="content_scroll scroll-pane">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <h3 class="left">Title...</h3>
            </div>
            <h4>Place: ...</h4>
            <h4>Date: ...</h4>
            <h4>Hour: ...</h4>
            <h4>length: ...</h4>
            ...
            ...
            ...
            <a href="" class="btn_registro2">Inscribirme</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need to open it with a click but content depends on other data.

How can I open my popup (after load necessary data) and edit it so that I can show it correctly? (I need to fill place, date, hour, length, etc...)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "other data" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `.slideDown()` in `load()` callback:

```
$('#popup_calendar').load(page, function ()
{
    $('#popup_calendar').slideDown(1000);
}
```

Comment: Yes sir, I finally did a php function that retrieves all html needed. Then I used jquery.get method to get that response and load my #popup_calendar div.